# Adding +1 to a mysql value every day

Tags: php, mysql

hello I have a table called 'members' for my website/php code and I dont know how to increase a certain value by 1 everytime a new day starts (or eventually everyday the user logs in the first time).

Can anyone help me?

-thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You're looking for this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43293/updating-a-column-after-expiration-of-specific-time-in-mysql

Comment: @trxdev no problem. Added it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in either where you process the user login, or in a file that's scheduled with a cron job:

For everyone:

```
UPDATE members SET field = field + 1;
```

For one person

```
UPDATE members SET field = field + 1 WHERE user_id = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this through searching or what not you could do something like the following:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -- enable event scheduler.
SELECT @@event_scheduler;  -- check whether event scheduler is ON/OFF
CREATE EVENT e_store_ts  -- create your event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 24 HOURS  -- run every 24 hours
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.youtable set mycolumn='1'
```

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43293/updating-a-column-after-expiration-of-specific-time-in-mysql